# How to implement pagination using multiple searcing criteria in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Im trying to implement pagination using multiple searching criteria.
Supposed I Have student table. I also use pagination when the list of student displayed.
The pagination link is. `site_url . '/student/page/';` so I use `$config['uri_segment'] = 1`;
so the pagination link will be

```
<a href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/0">1</a>
<a href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1">2</a>
```

and son.

After that I wanna search student data using 3 searching criteria implemented using textfield.

```
id  name    address.
```

user can search by id or name or address or combination of the three criteria. 
the url become

```
http://mysite/index.php/student/page/0
href=http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1
```

and son.

but  I use get method for searching.  and while trying to search using the search criteria field the url become

```
href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1?id=1&name=a&address=b
```

the problem occurred when I try create pagination based on criteria. because the pagination link have contain query string
i don't know how to create become

```
href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/0?id=1&name=a&address=b
href="http://mysite/index.php/student/page/1?id=1&name=a&address=b
```

or do you have a best practice to solve this problem ?

---

To solve that problem, I try using `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc()`. First I create array asocc for pagination link.

```
$array = array('id' => '001', 'name' => 'a', 'address' => 'canada');
```

the url become
`id/001/name/a/address/canada`. I use `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc()` function to get key and value of the segment.

```
array (
    id => 001,
    name=>a,
    address=>canada
)
```

but while there some searching criteria that not included while searching. let say, the user only search by name and address. the array become
`$array = array('id' => '', 'name' => 'a', 'address' => 'canada');` and the url `id/name/a/address/canada`
the assoc array become

```
array (
    id => name,
    a=>address,
    canada=>
)
```

the assoc array is not disorganized again. so I can't get the right value of the assoc array.
I think i will set the identifier to the searching criteria if not included. supposed i put `#`.

```
if isset($_GET['id']) then
$id = '#'
else 
$id = $_GET['id']

$array = array('id' => $id, 'name' => 'a', 'address' => 'canada');
```

How about that ... ? or if there are another best practice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've always found it somewhat a pain to deal with uri's in ci.
Is there a way you can set a default of some kind for your values if the user doesn't include that as part of their search? or even not include the key?  so it would return something like

```
id/10/name/false/address/canada
```

or

```
id/10/address/canada
```

then you can

```
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();

$id = array_key_exists("id", $uri) ? $uri['id'] : false;
$id = $id == 'false' ? false : $id;
$query .= $id ? "AND id = $id" : "";
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

When I use `uri_to_assoc`, I always have a default array, so in my application, I can always get the required parameter, even if it missing from the `uri`

```
$param_default = array('cat','page');
$param_array = $this->uri->ruri_to_assoc(3, $param_default);
```

Now I can safely access `$param_array['cat']` and `$param_array['page']` even when uri doesn't contain that parameter.

I always user `ruri_to_assoc` and `ruri_segment`, so the extra parameter always start in 3rd `uri` segment.